# View iOS App Raw Storage Data on PC

Tags: ios, memory, storage, ipod

We have developed a custom application for iOS and we believe there is some kind of memory leak or caching issue. In the settings tab "Storage and ICloud Usage", I need to view the applications stored data under "Storage". Is there anyway I can actually view the raw data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach your device to your mac.

In Xcode go to Window/Devices

Select your device on the top left, your  installed app in the center.

Scroll down to the bottom, click on the cog and select Download Container

Specify a destination folder and accept.

Right click on the file created and examine contents.

Comment: Are you all set with this?